# Tracking down where collection was modified (ConcurrentModificationException)

Tags: java

I have a list that represents a set of fields to be selected from my database. I am passing that off to a class I use to build out a select statement string. When building it, I am getting a ConcurrentModificationException whenever I check list#isEmpty. I changed it to an ImmutableList and I no longer get this problem.

However, this is confusing to me... Shouldn't I get an UnsupportedOperationException in the place that was modifying it concurrently?

Line throwing the exception:

```
if (list.isEmpty() || ... null checks) { ... }
```

Exception:

```
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1231)
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:1040)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.isEmpty(AbstractCollection.java:86)
```

SOLUTION:

The list I was checking for #isEmpty was a sublist. The main list was edited after the sublist was created (to add some required fields). This caused the ConcurrentModificationException when checking #isEmpty.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isEmpty()` should never throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. This is only ever thrown by using an Iterator while it has been modified (and only for some collections)

If a custom List implementation is throwing this exception it is not the expected behaviour so when you wrap it, I would expect it to no longer do this.

> I changed it to an ImmutableList and I no longer get this problem.

This most likely is copying rather than wrapping your list which is another reason you might not see this exception. (As you are using a copy not the mutated original)

> how could I possibly be getting the stacktrace I have.

I would call that a bug, or at least bad design.  It's not documented, nor does there appear to be a reason for it either.

Instead of taking a `subList()` you could take a copy of the subList() which is what I suspect you are doing.

Comment: So... then I suppose my question is... how could I possibly be getting the stacktrace I have...

Comment: Taking a subList()? This is java.util.ArrayList that's throwing this, not my own implementation.

Comment: So, maybe this is related though: when I originally take in the fields to be used, it is as a large array. So, I partition that array into smaller lists using Lists#partition. Then I iterate over those lists, making the statement strings... and when I check if the partition field list isEmpty, I get the exception.

Comment: @user2303325 when you take a subList of an ArrayList, if you *attempt* to modify the original in any way, you can no longer access the subList. It doesn't matter if this is in the same thread or another one.